# Clicking the white mass on opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Hello i'm tring to make color bot that makes clicking red colors with mouse. I used opencv for color filtering then i used mss for screen capture. i have nice results but i dont know how to make it click let me show you, as you can see in the picture i need to click the white part of masked object. How can i select that white mass?

[image: I want to click here]

```
    import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import mss

with mss.mss() as sct:


monitor = {"top": 1, "left": 1, "width": 250, "height": 250} 
# lower=np.array([0,139,208])
# upper=np.array([0,141,221 ]) #  minyon

lower=np.array([2,97,154])
upper=np.array([4,210,225 ])   #  hero

while "Screen capturing":

    img = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

    cv2.imshow("Maskelenmis", mask)
    
    

    # Press "q" to quit

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Take a look at [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)

Comment: Take a look at https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/

Comment: work through opencv's tutorials on docs.opencv.org and you will learn how to work with masks and contours and all that